# How to parse an array of json objects that are stringified in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How can i parse a string of an array of json objects in php(more specifically Laravel)? I have a hidden input on a form whose value i set using jquery. The value contains an array of json objects in form of a string that look like this:

```
"{"id":"1","qty":"2","sp":"140.00"},{"id":"17","qty":"2","sp":"100.00"},{"id":"27","qty":"6","sp":"80.00"},{"id":"22","qty":"6","sp":"60.00"}"
```

I want to parse this so that i can access the data as actual objects like:

```
//this gets the first object
$myInput[0];
//this gets the id of the first object
$myInput[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do what you want by this code (added '[ in the beginning and closing it in the last) :

```
$s = '[{"id":"1","qty":"2","sp":"140.00"},{"id":"17","qty":"2","sp":"100.00"},{"id":"27","qty":"6","sp":"80.00"},{"id":"22","qty":"6","sp":"60.00"}]';

$d =  json_decode($s);
echo $d[0]->id; // 1
```